# Reshape a numpy array for a given time series

Tags: python

How do you arrange a numpy array of a time-series into a matrix with 24 hours on one side and number of days on the other side ?

for example if I have a numpy array of temperature values starting at 3 hr on 4/4/2022 and ending 23 hr on 4/5/2022.  How do I arrange the temperature values into an array of shape 24x2 in this case ?

```
2022-04-04 03:00:00   -14.310345
2022-04-04 04:00:00   -15.910526
2022-04-04 05:00:00   -16.983607
2022-04-04 06:00:00   -16.913793
2022-04-04 07:00:00   -14.558333
2022-04-04 08:00:00   -12.308197
2022-04-04 09:00:00   -14.026667
2022-04-04 10:00:00   -14.249180
2022-04-04 11:00:00   -13.754237
2022-04-04 12:00:00   -15.513793
2022-04-04 13:00:00   -16.116667
2022-04-04 14:00:00   -16.140385
2022-04-04 15:00:00   -14.542593
2022-04-04 16:00:00   -11.738983
2022-04-04 17:00:00   -14.703333
2022-04-04 18:00:00   -16.401754
2022-04-04 19:00:00   -16.650000
2022-04-04 20:00:00   -14.365517
2022-04-04 21:00:00   -16.900000
2022-04-04 22:00:00   -16.805085
2022-04-04 23:00:00   -16.501639
2022-04-05 00:00:00   -13.478333
2022-04-05 01:00:00   -16.383333
2022-04-05 02:00:00   -16.833898
2022-04-05 03:00:00   -16.737705
2022-04-05 04:00:00   -13.729508
2022-04-05 05:00:00   -16.415254
2022-04-05 06:00:00   -16.845763
2022-04-05 07:00:00   -16.870833
2022-04-05 08:00:00   -14.007692
2022-04-05 09:00:00   -15.152727
2022-04-05 10:00:00   -15.581356
2022-04-05 11:00:00   -16.036667
2022-04-05 12:00:00   -13.496429
2022-04-05 13:00:00   -14.760656
2022-04-05 14:00:00   -16.254237
2022-04-05 15:00:00   -16.733333
2022-04-05 16:00:00   -11.578689
2022-04-05 17:00:00   -13.713333
2022-04-05 18:00:00   -15.933333
2022-04-05 19:00:00   -17.070492
2022-04-05 20:00:00   -15.570492
2022-04-05 21:00:00   -15.730508
2022-04-05 22:00:00   -17.370000
2022-04-05 23:00:00   -16.962295
```

Comment: Can you give an example on how the output should look like? Also, you ma use `pandas` to do so as it provides functions like [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Answer (score 0):

To reshape an array into a matrix, your data needs to have the correct length. In your exemplary case, the data would need to have a length of 48 records.

To reshape this array into 24x2, you can use [numpy's reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method, which will give a new shape to an array without changing its content.:

`data = np.reshape(data, (24,2), 'F')`

The "F" (Fortran Order) is required to achieve the desired ordering, elsewise the elements end up in wrong dimensions.

If you have data available for "a couple of days plus or minus", i would first
slice the correct amount of data from the array and then reshape it:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(10000)
days_to_extract = 12
start_index = 100
slice_of_data = data[start_index:start_index + (24 * days_to_extract)]
day_hour_matrix = np.reshape(slice_of_data, (24, days_to_extract), 'F')
```

Comment: thank you very much Scott and Christian.